# Integration Rear with bacula

Tags: ubuntu, backup, system-recovery, bacula

I am trying to integrate bacula community with Rear to have complete disaster recovery solution. But I don't really know how to configure bacula File Deamon nad local.conf file for Rear to be able to recover full machine from my backup - basic system from rear and rest of the file from bacula backup. Currently my local.conf config looks like this:

```
OUTPUT=PXE
BACKUP=BACULA
CLONE_ALL_USERS_GROUPS=y
OUT_URL="nfs://<address_and_path>/
OUTPUT_PREFIX=hostname
```

And my bconsole config is:

```
Director {
  Name = bacula-dir
  DIRport = 9101
  address = <director_address>
  Password = "QzGtEpKd7tBOy56l77veXBJzfqF0PB3hM"
}
```

Bacula client is normally visible by director and I am able to backup it, but when I try to

```
rear mkrescue
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2021-06-30 12:04:30.219770879 ERROR: Bacula client status unknown on director.
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Rear 2.5 and bacula 9.4.2.

I feel like there is almost none documentation about it or I just do not understand it properly, so if somebody can explain what I am doing wrong, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The client in the bacula configuration for your server must be named as `$(hostname -s)-fd`.

In addition, this works on a RHEL, but should work in you case too.  The root cause should be that your hostname contains a `-`.

You can edit file  /usr/share/rear/prep/BACULA/default/50_check_BACULA_bconsole_results.sh .  the line below define how is determined the client's name.  This client must exists in bconsole.

```
 #  /usr/share/rear/prep/BACULA/default/50_check_BACULA_bconsole_results.sh
 (...)
 BACULA_CLIENT=`grep $(hostname -s) /etc/bacula/bacula-fd.conf | grep "\-fd" | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d"-" -f1`
 (...)
```

Replace with suitable client name, make sure it is named as `$(hostname -s)-fd`.